# Check input value on click of button (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, input, onclick

I need to check if an input has value on the click of a button (not the submit button). It should be really simple, but not sure why this isn't working? It is in Gravity Forms and the button is the "next" button to continue the form.. This is what I have so far...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$('#gform_next_button_6_69').click(function(){                

    if($("#input_6_1").val().length == 0) {//to be applied if at least 1 input has no value
        alert("Has No Value");
    }
    else{
        alert("Has Value");
    }
});

}); /* end document ready */

<input type="button" id="gform_next_button_6_69" class="button gform_next_button" value="Next" tabindex="91" onclick="jQuery(&quot;#gform_target_page_number_6&quot;).val(&quot;6&quot;); jQuery(&quot;#gform_6&quot;).trigger(&quot;submit&quot;,[true]); ">

<input name="input_1" id="input_6_1" type="text" value="" class="medium" tabindex="49">
```

Comment: Missing document ready handler?

Comment: Can you please include the HTML for the two elements, and the context for the script (included in head, body, etc. and where).

Comment: IS the selector correct? Don't let a silly typo get ya.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('#button').click(function(){                   
        if( $("#inputID").val().length == 0) {
            alert("Has No Value");
        }
        else {
            alert("Has Value");
        }
    });

});
```

### [**SAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/n6N2S/)